# Dplyr mutate with variable number of column outputs

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to run a function of the following structure:

```
my_fun <- function(new_var_names, input_var_names, df){

df %>%
  mutate(...)

}
```

Where an indefinite number of new variables are generated. Their names use each element of a character vector `new_var_names` which has variable length. They are generated using as inputs the variables named in the character vector `input_var_names` using some functions `f1` and `f2`.

Also ideally this should be done within mutate and without using mapping or looping procedures.

Is it possible to adapt mutate to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are f1 and f2 defined?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach with `across` and `rename_at`. Who knows when `rename` will have `across` functionality added:

```
my_fun <- function(new_var_names, input_var_names, df){
  df %>%
    mutate(across(.cols = one_of(input_var_names), .names = "New.{.col}",
                  ~ . * 100)) %>%
    rename_at(vars(paste0("New.",input_var_names)),~new_var_names)
}

my_fun(c("NewX1","NewX2"),c("X1","X2"),data)
          X1       X2       X3        X4     NewX1    NewX2
1  76.512308 59.52818 35.45349 53.071453 7651.2308 5952.818
2  90.432867 53.60952 55.91350 87.441985 9043.2867 5360.952
3  82.226977 39.00973 14.58712 87.100901 8222.6977 3900.973
4   8.071753 32.63577 78.70822  3.345176  807.1753 3263.577
5   1.385738 81.03024 88.79939 97.613080  138.5738 8103.024
6   6.167663  5.15003 21.20549 49.532196  616.7663  515.003
7  86.789458 37.01053 77.29167 39.527862 8678.9458 3701.053
8  58.048272 85.80310 60.03993 42.337941 5804.8272 8580.310
9  32.070415 70.09671 95.80930 10.199656 3207.0415 7009.671
10 95.987113 68.76416 16.71015 17.019112 9598.7113 6876.416
```

You can replace `~ . * 100` with whatever function you want.

Sample Data:

```
data <- data.frame(replicate(4,runif(10,1,100)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can, look this:

```
data <- data.frame(L=letters,X=runif(26),Y=rnorm(26))

# Make a Cumsum in X and Y at the same time.

my_fun <- function(new_var_names, input_var_names, df) {
      
      df %>% mutate(across(.cols = input_var_names, 
                           .fns  = cumsum,
                           .names = paste0(new_var_names,'{.col}') ))
      
}

my_fun(new_var_names="cumsum_",input_var_names=c("X","Y"),df=data)


# Make a Cumsum and  CumMax in X and Y at the same time.

my_fun <- function(new_var_names, input_var_names, df) {
      
      df %>% mutate(across(.cols = input_var_names, 
                           .fns  = list(CumSum=cumsum,CumMax=cummax),
                           .names = paste0(new_var_names,'{.fn}_{.col}') ))
      
}

my_fun(new_var_names="New_",input_var_names=c("X","Y"),df=data)
```